# Issues with implementing object iterator for large nested objects

Tags: javascript

Imagine there's an object and we are trying to write a function that takes 'path' as an arugment and prints whatever is inside it. If the input is invalid, throw an error. The object size could be huge.

```js
const obj = {
  test: {
    demo: [{
      lname: 'dave'
    }]
  }
};

function getData(obj, dest) {
  const path = dest.split('.');
  return helper(obj, path);

  function helper(obj, path) {
    if (!path.length) return obj;
    const cur = path.shift();

    if ((Array.isArray(obj) && typeof obj === 'string') ||
      (typeof obj === 'undefined')) {
      throw new Error("Something wrong")
    }

    obj = obj[cur];
    return helper(obj, path);
  }
}

console.log(getData(obj, 'test.demo.0.lname'));
//console.log(getData(obj, 'test.demo.dave.lname')); // throws an error since in demo array you can't access 'dave'
```

I'm trying to figure out what are the shorter ways of writing this method? I heard someone say that we can write it couple lines.

Comment: You *could* write it in a couple of lines but you would have to skip the checks you are currently making, so running `getData({a: 1}, "a.b"`)` can fail in different ways.

Comment: Sure but can you give me the condensed version?

Comment: OK, I'll give you an answer. However, one point - when is this condition going to be true? `(Array.isArray(obj) && typeof obj==='string')`

Comment: `Array.isArray(obj) && typeof obj==='string'` That condition will never be `true`, because `Array.isArray` is basically equivalent to `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]"`, where a string would yield `"[object String]"`

Comment: @VLAZ what if my input is `console.log(getData(obj, 'test.demo.dave.lname'));` then it would break

Comment: But how can *an object* be both an array AND a string at the same time?

Comment: The object remains the same but the input might be invalid right? `test.demo.dave.lname` breaks it.. demo is an array and we are trying to access `dave` of demo. (Sorry if i'm not answering to your question?)

Comment: @TechnoCorner again, your check is `Array.isArray(obj) && typeof obj==='string'` so for it to be `true` the *same* item has to be an array and a string. I'm not asking what would break the function - I'm aware that missing keys do, the question is specifically about the condition that doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

An easy and short implementation can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iteratively take keys off an object as follows:

```js
const obj = {
  test: {
    demo: [{
      lname: 'dave'
    }]
  }
};

function getData(obj, dest) {
  var keys = dest.split(".");
  return keys.reduce(function(currentObject, key) {
    if(typeof currentObject == "undefined") throw Error("Something wrong");
    return currentObject[key];
  }, obj)
}

console.log(getData(obj, 'test.demo.0.lname'));
console.log(getData(obj, 'test.demo.dave.lname')); // throws an error since in demo array you can't access 'dave'
```

That's the more verbose option, to demonstrate what is happening, you can shorten it further

```js
const obj = {
  test: {
    demo: [{
      lname: 'dave'
    }]
  }
};

function getData(obj, dest) {
  return dest.split(".").reduce((curr, key) => curr[key], obj)
}

console.log(getData(obj, 'test.demo.0.lname'));
console.log(getData(obj, 'test.demo.dave.lname')); // throws an error since in demo array you can't access 'dave'
```

You can also avoid throwing errors but simply return `undefined` if a key is not found

```js
const obj = {
  test: {
    demo: [{
      lname: 'dave'
    }]
  }
};

function getData(obj, dest) {
  return dest.split(".").reduce((curr, key) => curr != undefined ? curr[key] : undefined, obj)
}

console.log(getData(obj, 'test.demo.0.lname'));
console.log(getData(obj, 'test.demo.dave.lname')); // undefined
```

However, while this is simple to implement, it's at the cost of error checking. Debugging what exactly went wrong could be really annoying as you have to know both what the data object and the destination inputs were then try and figure out what key was missing manually. So a longer implementation is usually better, if you want more robust and flexible code.

If you are using Lodash, then you can use their [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) which is even more robust and handles more syntax

```js
const obj = {
  test: {
    demo: [{
      lname: 'dave'
    }]
  }
};

console.log(_.get(obj, 'test.demo.0.lname'));
console.log(_.get(obj, 'test.demo[0].lname'));
console.log(_.get(obj, ['test', 'demo', 0, 'lname']));

console.log(_.get(obj, 'test.demo.dave.lname')); // undefined

console.log(_.get(obj, 'test.demo.dave.lname', 'this is not dave but the default vale'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why does it fail for 
`
const obj2 = {
  keys: {
    lists: [{
      firstName: 'dave'
    }]
  }
};
`

Comment: What key are you trying to get from it? And see - that's the issue with debugging I mentioned.

Comment: I am trying to get `obj2.keys.lists.0.firstName `

Comment: It works...if you invoke it as `getData(obj2, "keys.lists.0.firstName")` - if you tried `getData(obj2, "obj2.keys.lists.0.firstName")` then it wouldn't because there is no `obj2` key.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to use Lodash, then:

```
if(!_.has(obj,path)){
  //bad
}else{
  let val = _.get(obj,path);
}
```

If you don't care if some path not exists or it has `undefined` value, then you can just do:

```
let val = _.get(obj,path);
if(val===undefined){
  //bad
}
```

If you do care about sparse arrays and "empty slots", then don't rely on `_.has` method, because it returns `true` for empty slot.
Instead you can use alternative `_.exists` method from [Deepdash](https://deepdash.io/#exists) extension for Lodash.
This one will return false for empty slots carefully .